# What kind of props can I use for a future marine that is graduating high school?

Tags: photography-basics

I have a client that is going into the Marines after graduating high school. She wants to do her senior photos but wants them United States marine Corp inspired. How would I implement that into her pictures??

Comment: I think you should change your Question title. At the moment it doesn't mean anything really.

Comment: You could have gave your opinion on how I could implement that or what props I could use. Thanks but I'm not gonna change it

Comment: She should reconsider.  Since you are both not (currently) marines, you risk creating a caricature that her future self may find embarrassing or which the Marines may not appreciate.

Comment: Hi Danielle Carr, Welcome to Photography StackExchange. We hope you enjoy sharing knowledge and experience with us.

Comment: Agree with @xiota. She may be looking forward to being a marine and getting a photo in her dress blues - but that isn’t who she is today. You need to capture who she is today, not tomorrow.

Comment: Just an opinion... She will be a Marine... Probably this is the last chance for her to be a teen.

Answer (score 2):

Props won't do it.

Rather than props that can look tacky if they are not the real thing, try 
 **U S MARINE ATTITUDE.**

There's nothing cute, coy, or indirect about a **U S MARINE**.

Marines look directly into the camera and don't smile. Ask your subject to set their jaw. Clenching her teeth will accentuate the jaw line to portray a sense of power and willful intent.

In dress, emulate the crisp white starched collars, dark blue serge suit material and ever so slight touch of red.

Do a WEB search and look through the bunch of photos to see what they have in common insofar as your subject's expression and body position.

You don't want your subject holding a weapon or something that could brand her as some fringe militant by someone who doesn't make the right connection. If pushed too far, the school may even refuse using a photo that is too different from the mainstream established by school tradition. (I was a yearbook photographer and there were "rules" about acceptability - often decided afterward by some school "authority" when the photos were submitted and could be compared.)

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

First of all... she is still a teen. Let her have fun.

Second. If you do not have original stuff, like the uniform from mom or an aunt, a "prop" could be a bit unrespectful or [look like a "costume"](https://www.google.com/search?q=marine%20costume), so watch what stuff you use.

Even in that case, I would not put it on her or anything similar, probably more like a Teen looking forward to using the same uniform as her mom or something.

But I agree that the attitude, more than a prop is needed. Of course, you can be creative with the framing and light.

See the photo of this guy [from this movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/).

[image]

No props. But a general's face. As this is a photography "forum" explore this kind of dramatic light.

Get some inspiration for some movie scenes you find interesting in terms of attitude, light, framing pose, color grading. Not Props "needed".

A simple white Tshirt can work.